# How to disable NFS client caching?

Tags: nfs

I have a trouble with NFS client file caching. The client read the file which was removed from the server many minutes before.

My two servers are both CentOS 6.5 (kernel: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64)

I'm using **server A as the NFS server**, /etc/exports is written as:

```
/path/folder 192.168.1.20(rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,sync)
```

And **server B is used as the client**, the mount options are:

```
nfsstat -m

/mnt/folder from 192.168.1.7:/path/folder
Flags:  rw,sync,relatime,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=0,acregmax=0,acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,hard,noac,nosharecache,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.20,minorversion=0,lookupcache=none,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.7
```

As you can see, "lookupcache=none,noac" options are already used to disable the caching, but seems doesn't work...

I did the following steps:

1. Create a simple text file from server A
2. Print the file from the server B by cmd "cat", and it's there
3. Remove the file from the server A
4. Wait couple minutes and print the file from the server B, and it's still there!
5. But if I do "ls" from the server B at that time, the file is not in the output. The inconsistent state may last a few minutes.

I think I've checked all the NFS mount options...but can't find the solution.
Is there any other options I missed? Or maybe the issue is not about NFS?

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: There is kernel page cache that cannot be disabled. Maybe this what happens on the client side. Check if your nfs command reaches the network laye4 (using tcpdump and filter nfs protocol)..

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the same steps you have given with below parameters. Its working perfectly. I have added one more parameter "fg" in the client side mounting.

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o fg,noac,lookupcache=none XXX.XX.XX.XX:/var/shared/ /mnt/nfs/fuse-shared/
```